# Master page with content page and user control

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Below is my problem.

Scenario:

I have a Master Page, 3 Content Page(A,B, & C), and 1 web controls (Menu).

In my Master Page, I write all the jquery function of my Menu.

My Menu attached in every Page.

Problem?

My menu works fine in Page A, coz most of my functions run in Page A, but when I'm in Page B, my Menu doesn't  work anymore, only goes to the front page of Page A, function doesn't fire up.

Question?
How can I run my function when I change page or go back in my previous Page A. 
Anyone have the same problem? or anyone have a sample script?

Pls help...

**Master Page

```
function ShowEmployeePayslip() {

            var url = "pageA.aspx";
            if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE\s(?!9.0)/)) {
                var referLink = document.createElement("a");
                referLink.href = url;
                document.body.appendChild(referLink);
                referLink.click(function () {
                    ShowData1();
                    return false;
                });

            }

                // All other browsers
            else {
            window.location.replace(url);
            $(window).load(function () {
            ShowData1();                            
            });
            }



function ShowData1() {
            var Panel = document.getElementById("divData");

            if (Panel.style.display == "none" || Panel.style.display == "") {
                Panel.style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("DataGraph").style.display = "none";                                    }
            else {
                Panel.style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("DataGraph").style.display = "block";
            }

        }
```

**Menu

```
   <ul>
        <li><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkData1" runat="server">Page A Function</asp:LinkButton></li>
        <li><asp:HyperLink ID="LinkData2" NavigateUrl="PageB.aspx" runat="server">Page B</asp:HyperLink><li>
          <li><asp:HyperLink ID="LinkData3" NavigateUrl="PageC.aspx" runat="server">Page C</asp:HyperLink><li>
    </ul>


 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                { 
          LinkData1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:ShowData();e.preventDefault();");
        }
```

Thanks heap for the help...

Comment: Looks hard coded to me... `ShowEmployeePayslip1();`

Comment: yeh your right :( almost giving up now

Comment: Not trying to discourage you, I just don't have an answer. Uh, `.each()`, `find()`, etc, make an array of your data prior to `this` function, then it'll have its `vars` defined. Maybe even a `for` loop...? Trying to help :-(

Comment: You know what I do? Single script, and write `HTML` for every page. That way I have control [Here is my site](http://www.sinsysonline.com/repair/)

Comment: Nice website, thank you for the link. I'll take note of that, so next time my life would be easy.

Comment: Steal anything you want. All open source, GFX design by me, and a grid system to manage input. Enjoy! (I work at Amazon.com now. This site has been abandoned, but is still a good ref.)

Answer (score 0):

For the lack of proper understanding of what you are trying to do, I will have to ask questions as I go. But, I have some feedback on it:

1. Does the menu differ from page to page? if not, put the menu in the master page.
2. You should know that content pages can have their own scripts. If you need different menu in different pages, use this feature.

Now with the answer to your question, assuming the different pages will have different content and report types, look at using my tip at point 2 to have the same function "ShowData()" in every Content Page and not the Master Page.

If I am off, please let me know.

Comment: I have only one Menu attached  in all pages. Using Web Form User control. It's like include (.inc) in page.  Hope you get me.

Comment: just in case you ask me how much knowledge I have: I'm a beginner on this jquery thing. I'm self studying at the moment. Your help is really really much appreciated.